# What is an example of a uniformly continuous function but not absolutely continuous

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

Is there a function that is  uniformly continuous function but not absolutely  continuous.

My answer is $f(x)=x^{2}, \forall x\in R$

Is this right?

Are there any other?

Comment: Your example is not uniformly continuous. You cannot guarantee that for all real numbers a and b, there exists a delta such that |f(a) - f(b)| = |a^2 - b^2| < delta whenever |a-b| is small. You can make it uniformly continuous by restricting its domain to a bounded, closed subset of R (a closed interval [a, b])

Comment: @BartW , Is there a simpler example that is uniformly continuous  but not absolutely continuous?

Answer (score 1):

The Cantor function is an example.

Comment: Is there a simpler example?

Comment: @MrDi I would suppose that the Cantor function is the simplest function which is not absolutely continuous. If you have a simpler function which is continuous, but not absolutely continuous, you can restrict it to a compact interval.

Comment: I think your answer  is wrong cantor functions isn't uniformally continous

Comment: @Az264 It actually is. A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.